# Recreating a Vivado project from a TCL file without copying the sources over

Tags: tcl, vivado

I've used `write_project_tcl` to create a TCL script from a Vivado project which can then be used to re-create the project's structure. If I run the script via `vivado -mode batch`, it creates a directory structure and copies source HDL files into these newly created directories. Here's the relevant part of the directory tree:

```
$ tree SpaceInvaders.srcs/sources_1/imports/
SpaceInvaders.srcs/sources_1/imports/
└── _build-vivado
    ├── clash-syn
    │   └── verilog
    │       └── SpaceInvaders
    │           └── SpaceInvaders
    │               ├── SpaceInvaders.v
    │               ├── image.hex
    │               ├── null-SpaceInvaders-0-1024x8.hex
    │               └── null-SpaceInvaders-1-7168x8.hex
    └── xilinx-vivado
        └── src-hdl
            └── Top.v
```

Now I would like to change the script so that the source files are not copied over; instead, I'd like the generated `.xpr` project file to reference them in their original location.

The part of the TCL script that currently copies sources over is this bit:

```
# Set 'sources_1' fileset object
set obj [get_filesets sources_1]
# Import local files from the original project
set files [list \
 [file normalize "${origin_dir}/src-hdl/Top.v" ]\
 [file normalize "${origin_dir}/../clash-syn/verilog/SpaceInvaders/SpaceInvaders/SpaceInvaders.v" ]\
 [file normalize "${origin_dir}/../clash-syn/verilog/SpaceInvaders/SpaceInvaders/image.hex" ]\
 [file normalize "${origin_dir}/../clash-syn/verilog/SpaceInvaders/SpaceInvaders/null-SpaceInvaders-0-1024x8.hex" ]\
 [file normalize "${origin_dir}/../clash-syn/verilog/SpaceInvaders/SpaceInvaders/null-SpaceInvaders-1-7168x8.hex" ]\
]
set imported_files [import_files -fileset sources_1 $files]

# Set 'sources_1' fileset file properties for remote files
# None

# Set 'sources_1' fileset file properties for local files
# None

# Set 'sources_1' fileset properties
set obj [get_filesets sources_1]
set_property -name "top" -value "Top" -objects $obj

# Set 'sources_1' fileset object
set obj [get_filesets sources_1]
# Import local files from the original project
set files [list \
 [file normalize "${origin_dir}/ip/ClockWiz25.xci" ]\
]
set imported_files [import_files -fileset sources_1 $files]

# Set 'sources_1' fileset file properties for remote files
# None

# Set 'sources_1' fileset file properties for local files
set file "ClockWiz25/ClockWiz25.xci"
set file_obj [get_files -of_objects [get_filesets sources_1] [list "*$file"]]
set_property -name "generate_files_for_reference" -value "0" -objects $file_obj
set_property -name "registered_with_manager" -value "1" -objects $file_obj
if { ![get_property "is_locked" $file_obj] } {
  set_property -name "synth_checkpoint_mode" -value "Singular" -objects $file_obj
}
```

Just based on that comment in the file, I guess it would be a "remote source" that I'd like to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by replacing lines like

```
set imported_files [import_files -fileset sources_1 $files]
```

with

```
add_files -norecurse -fileset $obj $files
```

With this, the files are referenced in the resulting project file by their original path.